# Inverse of Homomorphism for product of cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I need to explicitly calculate the inverse of
$$
\mathbb{Z}/89081\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/229\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/389 \mathbb{Z}
$$
with
$$
a \mod 89081 \mapsto (a\mod 229, a\mod 389)
$$

Now I knew this: $\mathbb{Z}/229\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/389$ are cyclic and if an isomorphism exits between $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/mZ \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/nm\mathbb{Z}$ with the groups cyclic, this is equivalent to $\gcd(n,m)=1$, so I know that $\gcd(229,389)=1$. Now I suspect that it has something to do with finding the inverse of the element modulo, I am not sure, maybe you could give me a hint. It needs to be such an $a$ that the inner product is $a^{-1}$. What do I need to do to get there? Do I have to calculate the inverse of $229,389 \mod 89081$? And where to next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [chinese remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem): Indeed we first note that $229\cdot 389=89081$ and that $229$ and $389$ are coprime. So indeed your map is an isomorphism.

We want to construct an inverse. For this we are looking for two numbers $e_1,e_2$ such that $e_i\equiv\delta_{i,j}\pmod{m_j}$ for $i,j\in\{1,2\}$, where $m_1=229$ and $m_2=389$.

Indeed using the [Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm), we can find two integers $r,s$ such that $r\cdot m_1+s\cdot m_2=1$. By then setting $e_1=s\cdot m_2$ and $e_2=r\cdot m_1$, we have achieved our goal. Explicitly, we have $r=265+c\cdot 389$ and $s=-156-229\cdot c$ for any integer constant $c$ (that I will choose $=0$).

So $e_1=-60684$ and $e_2=60685$ will do the trick, i.e. we have the explicit inverse $$\mathbb{Z}/229\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/389 \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/89081\mathbb{Z}, \\(a,b)\mapsto- a \cdot60684+b\cdot60685\pmod{89081}$$

Comment: Thank you but I've got $73$ and $-124$ vor r and s using the extended euclidian algorithm?

Comment: @KingDingeling Your solutions correspond to choosing $c=-1$ instead of $c=0$, so our results are equivalent

Comment: Thank you, but how do you get the $265$ and $-156$?

Comment: @KingDingeling I am not sure if I understand your question correctly: We have $265=-124+389$ and $-156=73-229$ (if the question is *why I chose this pair over the other one*, then I can tell you that there is no reason, indeed it is completely arbitrary)

Comment: Thank you very Max for your time and help!

Comment: @KingDingeling You are welcome 

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Case_of_two_moduli).  The wikipedia page has constructive proofs using the extended Euclidean algorithm that can be used for implementation.

Note on "can be used":
The linked page searches for simultaneous solution of:
$$x=a_2 \mod n_1 \\ x=a_1 \mod n_2$$
In our case we have $n_1=229$, $n_2=389$ (or, if you prefer, $n_2=229$, $n_1=389$ in which case you have to adjust what follows accordingly).

Use the extended Euclidean algorithm to compute $m_1$ and $m_2$ such that
$$1=m_1n_1 + m_2n_2$$
which is possible because our moduli are relatively prime. Then the solution is
$$x = a_2m_1n_1 + a_1m_2n_2$$
This establishes a mapping $(a_1,a_2)\mapsto x$ where $x$ is a function of $a_1$ and $a_2$:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb Z/n_1\mathbb Z \times Z/n_1\mathbb Z &\to \mathbb Z/n_1n_2\mathbb Z\\
(a_1,a_2)&\mapsto x=x(a_1,a_2)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you, but what do you mean by "use" it, I mean use it to...?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and time.